# $x \mapsto h(x)-\alpha \lvert \lvert x\rvert\rvert ^{2}$ convex and $x$ minimizer of $h$, then $h(y)-h(x)\geq \alpha\lvert \lvert y-x\rvert\rvert^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization, convex-analysis

Assume that we are looking at the space $\mathbb R^{n}$ with norm $\lvert \vert \cdot \rvert \rvert_{\text{euclid}}$ and then assume the function $x \mapsto h(x)-\alpha \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert ^{2}$ is convex with $\alpha > 0$ and let be $x^{*}$ a minimizer of $h$. Is it true that $h(y)-h(x^{*})\geq \alpha\lvert \lvert y-x^{*}\rvert\rvert^{2}$?

I do not know where to begin, I do not understand how convexity of $x \mapsto h(x)-\alpha \lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert ^{2}$ actually helps

I will assume that $0<\lambda < 1$ By convexity, we have that:

$$ h((1-\lambda)y+\lambda x)-\alpha\lvert \lvert(1-\lambda)y+\lambda x \rvert \rvert^{2} \leq (1-\lambda)[h(y)-\alpha\lvert \lvert y\rvert \rvert ^{2}]+\lambda[h(x)-\alpha\lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert ^{2}]$$

Where to from here?

Comment: Is $x^*$ a minimizer of $h$ or of the convex function?

Comment: $x^{*}$ is a minimizer of $h$

Comment: Is your function $C^2$?

Comment: Then use Taylor formula with Laplace integral remainder.

Comment: @blamethelag sorry it is not $C^2$, I checked again

Comment: Is it differentiable?

Comment: No, need not be, I was attempting to work with subgradients